# Confusion between uint8_t and unsigned char

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, uint8t

I am trying to call `void process (uint8_t* I1,uint8_t* I2,float* D1,float* D2,const int32_t* dims);` from a header file, using the following

```
    int n=10;
    size_t size=n*n*sizeof(uint8_t);
    uint8_t* I1 = (uint8_t*)malloc(size);
    uint8_t* I2 = (uint8_t*)malloc(size);
    size=n*n*sizeof(float);
    float* D1=(float*)malloc(size);
    float* D2=(float*)malloc(size);
    const int32_t dims[3] = {n,n,n};
    process(I1,I2,D1,D2,dims);
```

but when I compile, using g++ on linux, I get the message `undefined reference to process(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, float*, float*, int const*)`
Why does this happen?

Comment: I am writing C++, I guess the reason I didn't think I should more code is that I don't understand in the first place, why the compiler didn't find the function process regardless of what it does. There is something I think is worth mentioning in the top of the header file.

` #ifndef _MSC_VER `
 ` #include <stdint.h> `
` #else` 
  ` typedef __int8            int8_t; `
  `#endif `

Comment: `uint8_t` is likely just a type alias for `unsigned char`. Similarly, `int32_t` for `int`. The problem is that you don't link the proper object file/library.

Comment: *undefined reference* is a linker issue, you have to **link** with appropriate library. see [what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix).

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, you are correct, thank you

Comment: There is almost never any point in using `malloc` in C++.

Comment: what's a better alternative ? (I am new to c++)  @molbdnilo 
I am familiar with std::vector , are there any other alternatives ?

Comment: `std::vector` is the best alternative (`std::vector<uint8_t> I1(n * n);`, then pass `I1.data()`, and so on). If you desperately need manual memory management, `new uint8_t[n*n]` (and remember to `delete []`).

Answer (score 2):

> , I get the message undefined reference to process(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, float*, float*, int const*) Why does this happen?

It happens because the linker was not able to find the *definition* for the function `process(...)`. If this function comes from a library, this means that you are not linking to the library which contains the definition for this function.

Also, `uint8_t` is just an alias for `unsigned char` in gcc.

Moreover, you shouldn't manually manage the memory when you have a very simple and safe solution in the form of `std::vector`. Code without any `malloc`s:

```
    size_t size = n * n;
    std::vector <uint8_t> I1 (size);
    std::vector <uint8_t> I2 (size);

    std::vector <float> D1(size);
    std::vector <float> D2(size);

    const int32_t dims[3] = {n,n,n};

    process(&I1[0], &I2[0], &D1[0], &D2[0], dims);
```

Comment: `size = n * n * sizeof(float);` - these calculations no longer needs to be in bytes - it should be in elements (i.e. just `n * n`), to size the `vector`s properly.

Answer (score 0):

> Confusion between uint8_t and unsigned char ... Why does this happen?

Simply because `uint8_t` is a type alias of `unsigned char` on your system. These two are the same type. This is normal.

> undefined reference to process ... Why does this happen?

It appears that you've failed to define the function that you call.

---

P.S. Avoid `malloc` in C++. Also avoid owning bare pointers. Your example program leaks memory.

> what's a better alternative ? (I am new to c++)

Use `std::vector`.